# What is the minimum energy of a photon for the reaction to occur?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, collision

If a photon with sufficient energy interacts with a stationary proton, the reaction occurs
$$\gamma+p\to p+\pi^0$$

What is the minimum energy of a photon $E_\textrm{min}$ for this reaction to occur.

I've heard that the way to find minimum energy is to use reference frame in which both proton and $\pi$ meson have zero velocity after the collision. I've tried this approach and I've even gotten the energy of the photon in this reference frame as
$$E_\gamma'=\frac{m_\pi^2+2m_pm_\pi}{2(m_p+m_\pi)}c^2$$

However I'm having problems with transforming this energy back to the original reference frame. Is this the right approach to this problem?

Comment: One strategy is outlined in my answer to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/687451/lowest-kinetic-energy-of-particle-for-which-reaction-is-possible-invariant-mass

Comment: You have been taught about the relativistic invariant $E^2-p^2c^2$, which, as the name implies, is the same in every frame. So you *never* have to transf0rm anything. This quantity is the same in the "before" lab frame and the "after" CM frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **think geometrically**
(using the strategy of the answer I referenced in the comment:
[Lowest kinetic energy of particle for which reaction is possible (invariant mass)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/687451/lowest-kinetic-energy-of-particle-for-which-reaction-is-possible-invariant-mass)),
**one need not "transform" to the COM-frame and back.**

Draw an **energy-momentum diagram**.
Your problem in this threshold case is akin to a problem involving the doppler effect [Two timelike vectors with a common tail, whose tips are joined by a lightlike vector.].

When you say

> reference frame in which both proton and  meson have zero velocity after the collision.

that means that the 4-momenta of the final products are parallel (collinear).
[That is, what is generally not-parallel is, in the threshold case, parallel. What would have been a quadrilateral with three timelike vectors (two of which have equal mangitude) and a lightlike vector, you instead have *a triangle with two timelike vectors (one with the invariant-mass $m_p+m_{\pi}$) and a lightlike vector*.]

The Doppler factor (Bondi k-factor) $k=\exp\theta$
can be expressed in terms of the proton mass and the invariant mass, $(m_p+m_{\pi})$. The $\theta$ is the rapidity [Minkowski-angle] so that velocity $v=\tanh\theta$ and time-dilation factor $\gamma=\cosh\theta$.

With $k$ known, the rapidity-angle $\theta$ can then be used to solve for an unknown leg of Minkowski right triangle using hyperbolic-trig functions of $\theta$.

*It's like solving for an unknown component in a free-body diagram. Try it!*

[Using $m_p=938$ and $m_\pi=135$, I get 144.715.]

Looking at your answer, it's close... hint: *think Doppler effect.*